# Spark job failing on Dataproc (it works on Databricks), error messages not clear to me

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

Update: I needed to increase the memory on the Dataproc nodes, but I couldn't get to the Spark UI for various reasons to see why the executors were dying. Coming back to this project with a little more Spark and GCP experience allowed me to quickly solve the issue.

====

I've been trying for a long time to get the predict phase of the ALS recommender model in pyspark to run on Dataproc. Update: Confirmed that this code does run successfully on Databricks.

Code:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test-mf").getOrCreate()
model = ALSModel.load("gs://my-dataproc-bucket/trained-model")
userRecs = model.recommendForAllUsers(100).collect()
```

(I'm just doing the "collect" since it seems like the simplest operation to get the code to actually work--I was originally doing some select statements to try to process the data and that was failing as well.)

I get a ton of error messages, in a relatively quick time span (maybe 15 minutes from starting the job to final failure), none of which mean much to me or have yielded an easy smoking gun from googling.

Here's the last set of logs, let me know if you need anything earlier:

```
 18/03/27 22:38:59 WARN org.apache.spark.ExecutorAllocationManager: No stages are running, but numRunningTasks != 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/be3c5758e6694a4ca7f2911043f7a173/spark-matrix-factorization.py", line 35, in <module>
    userRecs = model.recommendForAllUsers(100).collect()
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 438, in collect
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o50.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 4.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 4.0 (TID 26, my-dataproc-cluster-w-1.c.my-gcp-project.internal, executor 10): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 10 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container marked as failed: container_1520973147661_0018_01_000012 on host: my-dataproc-cluster-w-1.c.my-gcp-project.internal. Exit status: 1. Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1520973147661_0018_01_000012
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:972)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:869)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:1170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:84)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1499)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1487)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1714)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1669)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1658)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2022)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2043)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2062)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2087)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:936)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:278)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply$mcI$sp(Dataset.scala:2803)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2800)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2800)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2823)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:2800)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

18/03/27 22:38:59 INFO org.spark_project.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Stopped Spark@446a8845{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4040}
18/03/27 22:38:59 WARN org.apache.spark.ExecutorAllocationManager: Attempted to mark unknown executor 10 idle
ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.jobs.submit.pyspark) Job [be3c5758e6694a4ca7f2911043f7a173] entered state [ERROR] while waiting for [DONE].
```

I've been trying to see if there's more logs anywhere that could give me a more informative error message, but had no luck getting the proxy set up to see the UI in Dataproc and didn't find any messages after running gcloud dataproc clusters diagnose.

In response to Dennis below,

Machine types:

**Master node**

Standard (1 master, N workers)

*Machine type*

n1-standard-4 (4 vCPU, 15.0 GB memory)

*Primary disk size*

500 GB

**Worker nodes**

2

*Machine type*

n1-standard-4 (4 vCPU, 15.0 GB memory)

*Primary disk size*

500 GB

*Local SSDs*

0

Data size:

The entire trained ALS model (which contains all the data already) is only 104M.

Count instead of collect gives a similar problem:

```
18/03/28 22:37:08 ERROR org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 3 in stage 4.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
18/03/28 22:37:08 WARN org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.3 in stage 4.0 (TID 18, my-dataproc-cluster-w-1.c.my-dataproc-cluster.internal, executor 6): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 6 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container marked as failed: container_1520973147661_0019_01_000008 on host: my-dataproc-cluster-w-1.c.my-dataproc-cluster.internal. Exit status: 1. Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1520973147661_0019_01_000008
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:972)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:869)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:1170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:84)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1

18/03/28 22:37:08 WARN org.apache.spark.ExecutorAllocationManager: No stages are running, but numRunningTasks != 0
18/03/28 22:37:08 WARN org.apache.spark.ExecutorAllocationManager: Attempted to mark unknown executor 6 idle
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/9d05f24785474f1f84720daa115af584/spark-matrix-factorization.py", line 35, in <module>
    userRecs = model.recommendForAllUsers(100).count()
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 427, in count
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o50.count.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 4.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.3 in stage 4.0 (TID 19, my-dataproc-cluster-w-1.c.my-dataproc-cluster.internal, executor 6): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 6 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container marked as failed: container_1520973147661_0019_01_000008 on host: my-dataproc-cluster-w-1.c.my-dataproc-cluster.internal. Exit status: 1. Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1520973147661_0019_01_000008
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:972)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:869)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:1170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:84)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1499)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1487)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1714)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1669)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1658)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2022)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2043)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2062)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2087)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:936)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:278)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2430)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2429)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$55.apply(Dataset.scala:2837)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:2836)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.count(Dataset.scala:2429)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

18/03/28 22:37:08 INFO org.spark_project.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Stopped Spark@ee58b0b{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4040}
ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.jobs.submit.pyspark) Job [9d05f24785474f1f84720daa115af584] entered state [ERROR] while waiting for [DONE].
```

Comment: What machine types are you using? How large is your dataset? What happens if you call "count()" instead of collect()? Collect() will be shipping the entire distributed dataset to your single driver program, which might be OOMing.

Comment: @DennisHuo updated the question with answers to your questions.

Comment: Any remarkable differences with the Databricks setup: Spark version, Node memory, etc.? Have you experimented with other cluster setups?